# How can I source configuration data in an R package function?

Tags: r, config, r-package

If I were to use a configuration file in a normal R script, I would do this:

**config.R**

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
```

**RScript**

```
source('config.R')
d = a+b+c
Do stuff
```

How would I do this inside an R package? Can I keep a config file and source it inside an R function? Or should I include a,b,c in every function? What's the best practice?

Comment: Shall the sourced config file be contained in the package or outside of the package?

Comment: Into which environment shall the configuration be sourced? The callers ("global") or the package environment?

Answer (score 1):

If the configs shall be contained in the R package itself:

1. Store the config file(s) in the `inst/configs` folder.
   After the package installation the configs are contained in the `configs` folder of the package location (`libPaths()`)
2. Source the config file using the package installation directory from within a package function:

```
myPackage::load_config <- function(config_file_name = "default_config.R",
                                   config_file_path = system.file("configs", package = getPackageName(), mustWork = TRUE))
{
    env <- new.env()     # all values are then contained in an separate environment
    # env <- globalenv() # to make the variables visible in the client's environment 
    config_file_FQN <- file.path(config_file_path, config_file_name)
    source(config_file_FQN, local = env, keep.source = TRUE)
    return(env)
}
```

3. The client can then trigger the configuration and use it (eg. pass around)

```
# client call
myConf <- myPackage::load_config()
print(myConf$YourVariableName))
```

Or store the environment with the configured variables within the package
as a package-global variable, see this example code (sorry, too much to explain here):
https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog/blob/master/R/zzz.R#L47

Comment: Sorry for digging up this old post. Your solution looks great but does not work for me. I installed the package locally but system.file("configs", package = getPackageName()) points to the folder in my home directory (where I compiled the tar.gz and from where I installed), not to my libpath. Any advice?

Comment: I'd guess that the `lib.loc` argument of `system.file()` must be set explicitly somehow instead of using the default value `NULL`. Basically I suspect that you have the package installed twice and `library` loads from your home folder instead of another path since it comes first in the `.libPaths` (so `system.file.` returns the correct path to home). Check the output of `.libPaths`. I suggest to open a new question containing a minimal reproducible example since it is difficult to diagnose without more input.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** One option would be to have these as default values in your functions. As in 
`my_fun <- function(..., a = 1, b = 2)` so on.

**2:** Given that what you have in a package is functions, you can easily have them declared in your main functions. So, the other functions being called by these have access to them.

**3:** Another option would be to keep them as functions.

```
a <- function() 
      a <- 1
```

Now you can call `a()` when ever you want, as in `a() + 2`.

**4:** Another option would be to use environments. I haven't use those much. I think you'll find [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) useful, in particular the section on **Package state**.

Comment: For now, I have kept an excel sheet, which I convert to Rda and store in /data/